# How to force Microsoft Azure .NET API calls to fail?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure, azure-sdk-.net

I am building an application that leverages Microsoft Azure and I am using Microsoft Azure .NET API calls for managing my infrastructure. I want to move to the testing phase, and I am curious if there are ways to force the calls to fail other providing bogus parameters.

For instance, I have the following snippet of code which powers on a VM. Is there a way to get this call to automatically fail when given correct parameters?

```
using (ComputeManagementClient client = new ComputeManagementClient(new CertificateCloudCredentials(c_subscriptionId, MyCert)))
        {
            var status = client.VirtualMachines.Start(serviceName, deploymentName, vmName);
            if (status.Status == OperationStatus.Failed)
            {
                throw new MachineCreationException(status.Error.Code, null);
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Agree with Cameron's answer below, another instance this will fail would be when the max Cloud Services allocated for your subscription has been reached.

Comment: @rharrison33 Please accept my answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following up on my (now removed) comment, `ComputeManagementClient` implements `IComputeManagementClient`. (See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.management.compute.computemanagementclient%28v=azure.11%29.aspx) for details.) An easy way would be to stub up an instance of `IComputeManagementClient` using a mocking framework. (I use [Rhino Mocks](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-mocks).)

There are plenty of resources available for writing unit tests with Rhino Mocks, and other mocking frameworks.